# Dynamically change ul from horizontal to vertical

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Maybe a duplicated question, but I didn't found any solution for this problem...

I have a `div` element (let's call it `master`) and don't have control over it.
So, I cannot modify its width or height.

Inside it I have another `div` (let's call it `container`), about which I have control.
And inside this `div` I have 3 `ul` elements, each with 240px.

**What I wish is**:

If the `master` has less than 720px (240px of each `ul` multiplied by the number of `ul's`), I want to show the `ul` elements vertically (one on top over the other).
But if the `master` has more than 720px, I want to show the `ul` elements horizontally (side by side).

Besides that, I would like that my `container` element had the minimum width possible to fit its `ul` children.

Is this possible using *only* css/html?

I already tried to use flex, float and tables without success...
I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qywozaa8/) to help.

**To illustrate what I wish:**

[image]

[image]

The gray box is the `master` element.
The red one is the `container`.
And the green ones are the `ul` elements.

Comment: Sure this is possible, have you looked at Bootstrap at all? Check out their grid system > http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: I think you will need JS to detect width of master div. Using `flex` and `flex-wrap` you might get close

Comment: @fauverism Yes, I did. But unfortunately I cannot use it, because I'm creating a plugin and Bootstrap isn't available to use...

Comment: @ovokuro I tried to use `flex` and `flex-wrap`, but I couldn't make the `container` element has the smallest width to fit its children

Comment: You could just copy the properties from bootstrap and apply them to your elements.

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qywozaa8/2/.

You can use `float:left` for ul elements.
Also you have to take care of padding with the width (have reduced it 230px as padding is 5px).
Also have changed container `overflow:auto` to `overflow-y: auto`.

Hope this helps.

**Updated css:**

```
div.master {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 720px;  /* I have no control over this. But this value can different (360, 1080 and so on) */
  height: 405px; /* I have no control over this. But this value can different (270, 607 and so on) */
}

div.container {
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 760px;
  /* we can add other attributes here */
}

ul.list {
  background-color: green;
  width: 240px; /* I have control over this element, but this value cannot be changed */
  height: 150px; /* I have control over this element, but this value cannot be changed */
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px; /* I have control over this element, but this value cannot be changed */
  /* we can add other attributes here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But this solution still doesn't meet the requirement of "make the `container` with the smallest width to fit the `ul` elements". So, when the `master` div is small, there are too much space between the `ul` elements and the scrollbar...

Comment: @LucasCosta Check the updated fiddle does it help https://jsfiddle.net/qywozaa8/3/. I have added text-align:center for container and removed the float property from list items. Also added disaply:inline-block to list items. I am not sure if you are supporting all the widths combinations, if so i think we have to use media queries to properly draw the layout